# How to create Google API line chart using PHP array / JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a simple Google line chart using their API. Hard coded, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales'],
      ['2010',  1000.31],
      ['2011',  1170.68],
      ['2012',  660]
    ]);

    var options = {

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
```

However, I am trying to populate the chart values using data from MySQL. How do I get this to work?

```
$arr = array('Year' => 'Sales', '2010' => 1000.31, '2011' => 1170.68, '2012' => 660);
$chart_data = json_encode($arr);

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $chart_data ?>);

    var options = {

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Basically, I am creating a PHP array from a MySQL result and trying to display its contents in the Google chart.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the below link code and its in  php and gd library and very simple to integrate with application.
http://www.kidslovepc.com/php-tutorial/php-dynamic-chart-plot.php.

Comment: This is an alternative solution, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post but for anyone else who finds it I just wanted to post this which is the obvious answer:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

$string = file_get_contents("sampleData.json");
echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

?>
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

To use a database, you would simply have to generate an array of columns and an array of rows and then `json_encode` them and return that instead of the .json file via PHP.

Comment: Who is downvoting my answer?  This is the solution to the problem "How to create Google API line chart using PHP array / JSON?"  Got a problem?  What is it?